Save email attachment giving it a name that consists of text found in email body
I want, with text found in the body of an email, for example, "order-33", to look in the attachment (DOC and PDF files) for order number 12345.
The words "order number" are always in attachment, but the numbers are different.
I want to save the attachment in the folder c:\temp, giving it a name that consists of the order number.
In this case, the DOC-file must be saved as PDF.
Below is code that only saves the attachment to the folder.
Sub SAVE_ATT (item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String 
Dim olMail As Variant
saveFolder = "С:\TEMP\"
For Each objAtt In item.Attachments
    If (InStr(1, olMail.Body, "order-33", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then      
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.FileName
    End If       
    Set objAtt = Nothing        
Next objAtt 
End Sub


See Forwarding Outlook emails based on specific content in attachments. First save the attachment then open it to parse with Word VBA.

Manipulate Excel via Outlook VBA demonstrates saving then opening.
